# Django dropdown menu/form based on model entries

Tags: django, django-forms

I have got created a drop down menu where I can show the values of a model data called "Items". However, I trying to change this into a Django form in order to be more flexible. However, I have some problems in understanding how to adapt this?

Here is the relevant code:

**models.py**

```
class Items(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
  def details(request):    
    template = loader.get_template('news/details.html')    
    items = Items.objects.all()
    context = {'items': items}      
    return  HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**details.html**

```
  <form method="POST" action = "">
   {% csrf_token %}    
   <select name = "wwww">
   {% for n in prod %}
     <option value ="{{ n.product_name }}"} name ="val">{{ n.product_name }} </option>
   {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="speichern1" value="1"/>
</form>
```

Maybe someone could help me out or point me to a help page for this?

Thanks, Andi

Comment: Use a [form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) with a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Abdul said above in the comments, using a `forms.py` file with a [form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/) would be best.

Within the Django forms documentation there is a lot of great information. In **The View** section of that link, that's what I use in my Django website. I.E. if POST(post it) else get a fresh form.

To make a form that directly mimics a Django model use a ModelForm. You can still override individual fields, exclude fields, etc. as exampled below.

a ModelChoiceField provides a dropdown list with choices (a combobox). A typical use for this is with a ForeignKeyField where it provides choices from the foreign key.

Example:

```
class ExampleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    item_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label="Item Choices", queryset=Items.objects.all(), required=True
    )
```

This example will pull all EquipmentMake objects and list them in the `ModelChoiceField`
If you want to restrict the choices on the list just update the Django Queryset it takes.

In your view something like:

```
def details(request):
    form = ExampleModelForm()
    return  HttpResponse(template.render(context, request, {"form": form}))
```

You can find more code examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/52461/django.forms.ModelChoiceField).